# Header files not being found (sys/stat.h)

Tags: raspbian, kernel, driver

I am trying to compile a device driver to control some LEDs connected via GPIO pins. First, I got errors that `/lib/modules/4.14.31-v7+/build` was not found, so I ran `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headersmade` a symlink from `/lib/modules/4.14.30-v7+/build/` to the folder it was searching.

I have the following includes:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Basically nothing from `sys/stat.h` to the end is found by compiler. I found `stat.h` and `types.h` in `/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/` and made a symlink to `/usr/include/sys`, which did not help. Instead, I tried

```
#include </usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/stat.h>
#inclue </usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/types.h>
```

which then caused the compiler to throw an error

```
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/stat.h:25:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
 #include <features.h>
```

I tried commenting out the `sys/*.h` files and then had the compiler throw an error for `fcntl.h`, and kept going and pretty much every other header was not being found.

FWIW I also tried rpi-update and rebooted. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I think you need to install certain dev libraries... they will probably be something like `sudo apt-get install lib*-dev`, where I have no idea what `*` should be

Answer (score 1):

The headers that were failing to include are user space only, so it was expected behaviour.  @Aurora0001: you are correct that I had also some missing kernel headers I had to install.

Thank you